# Динамическое добавление компонентов

Tags: android, java

Добрый вечер, Хеш.
Есть задача, при создании нового активити, добавлять на него некоторый набор компонентов, при чем этот набор будет зависеть от параметра который я передам через интент. Собственно вопрос, как создать такие наборы компонентов( допустим кнопка и едит ), я так подозреваю это будет обыкновенный леяут. И как добавить эти компоненты на активити во время работы приложения.

И еще один маленький вопрос. Допустим мне нужно получить 10 данных, но "тулить" 10 едитов как то не удобно. Есть ли альтернативное решение??

Спасибо

Comment: Что такое "тулить"? :))

Comment: @Deadkenny я извиняюсь за мой сленг) в данном контексте я словом "тулить" хотел показать как некрасиво будет размещение 10 едитов на 1 окне))

Comment: В многострочный TextView выводить например.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html)

Answer (score 0):

создай класс в объект которого будешь передавать необходимые параметры, затем передавай этот объект его через интент, в нужной активити получай этот объект и создавай нужные компоненты.

Comment: передать данные в другое активити не проблема. Тут самая соль в динамическом изменении вида активити. И Fragment с этим идеально справляется, спасибо ответу выше)